# Apply Excel bitwise function (BITAND or BITOR) to a range with large values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, bit-manipulation, worksheet-function

Since these are commutative and associative operators, I see no reason why they should be limited to two arguments.

I can use the following VBA function that I wrote for non-negative `Long` values up to 2<sup>31</sup>, but it will overflow for anything larger.

```
Function RangeBitOr(rng As Range) As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range

i = 0
For Each cell In rng
    i = i Or CLng(cell.Value)
Next cell

RangeBitOr = i

End Function
```

Excel's built in functions `BITAND` and `BITOR` (introduced in Excel 2013) can handle values all the way up to 2<sup>48</sup> - 1 and I'd like this capability applied to a range.

Is there a simple way to get these bit operators to work on a range up to this limit?

A couple of workarounds I've tried:

1. Creating two new columns and using `MOD` to split up larger values into two smaller ones, then using my `RangeBitOr` function on each of those and then putting the values back together.
2. Creating a column for the `BITOR` function to combine a running aggregate with the current value and taking the last one as my total `BITOR` for the range.

Ideally, I'd like to have a solution that doesn't require helper columns or VBA, but I'm open to any useful suggestions.

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Excel?

Comment: It don't have a 64 bit install handy, but put the value 9223372036854770000 in cell A1 and see what `Debug.Print TypeName(Range("A1").Value)` returns.

Comment: If I do that it's a double.

Comment: OK, that's the same as 32 bit.  You *should* be able to use a [LongLong](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11785/longlong#t=201608050023460585589) data type instead of a Long.  I'd give that a go - just replace all the `Long`'s with `LongLong` and the `CLng()` cast to `CLngLng()`.

Comment: I'd test it though - since Excel marshals to a `Double`, there could be loss of precision in the cast if the input value is greater than 9,007,199,254,740,992.

Comment: Awesome! It works at least up to that limit (and I don't have a need for anything greater).

Comment: Go ahead and post that as a self answer - like I said, I have no way to test it (and I'm rep-capped for the day anyway).

Answer (score 2):

As @Comintern points out in the comments, my VBA function can be extended up to at least the `BITOR` limit of 2<sup>48</sup> - 1 (possibly up to 9,007,199,254,740,992 = 2<sup>53</sup> or higher) by simply replacing `Long` with `LongLong` as follows:

```
Function RangeBitOr(rng As Range) As LongLong
Dim i As LongLong
Dim cell As Range

i = 0
For Each cell In rng
    i = i Or CLngLng(cell.Value)
Next cell

RangeBitOr = i

End Function
```

If anyone has a non-VBA solution, I'm still interested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any pure formula solutions unless MS decides to extend the function to include ranges

But if you want you can still manually use a workaround formula like

```
=BITOR(A1, BITOR(B1, BITOR(C1, BITOR(D1))))
```

The same method can be used for `BITAND`

---

If you can spend some space to reduce manual typing effort then you can

- Enter `=BITOR(value1, value2)` in the first cell
- Drag it *horizontally* `n - 2` times and *vertically* the same number of times for a list of `n` values
- Do the same for the remaining rows/columns with one less cell for each row/column

The result is like this for ORing 4 values, with the final result in cell D1

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | =BITOR(A1, A2) | =BITOR(B1, B2) | =BITOR(C1, C2) |
| 2 | 4 | =BITOR(A2, A3) | =BITOR(B2, B3) |  |
| 3 | 8 | =BITOR(A3, A4) |  |  |
| 4 | 16 |  |  |  |

You can also use array formula for large number of values for reducing the dragging effort, file size and improve speed

- On the first column select 3 cells, type `=BITOR(A1:A3, A2:A4)` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click the drag handle and drag the column horizontally 2 more times. The result will be similarly put in cell D1 like above

Comment: You don't need all of the `n-1` columns. You can just do `=BITOR(A(n), B(n-1))` in the `B` column (except `B1 = A1`).

Comment: @AlexisOlson but then you can't quickly drag the formula anymore

Comment: I don't see why not. Set `B1 = A1` and `B2 = BITOR(A2, B1)` and autofill down.